# Slim Framework -> Create XML Output

Tags: php, xml, twig, slim

How can i create a View that outputs real XML Content for an RSS Stream. I am using SLIM, TWIG for templating in Combination with Paris and Idiorm.

Something like :

```
$app -> get('/rss/', function() use ($app) {
$articles = Model::factory('Article') -> order_by_desc('timestamp') -> find_many();
return $app -> render('rss.xml', array('articles' => $articles));
});
```

With this Template layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
```

And this special Template for the Route RSS:

```
{% extends 'layout.xml' %}
{% block content %}     
<blog_content>
{% for article in articles %}
<article>
<article_id>{{ article.id }}</article_id>
<article_headline>{{ article.title }}</article_headline>
<article_author>{{ article.author }}</article_author>
<article_timestamp>{{ article.timestamp }}</article_timestamp>
<article_summary>{{ article.summary }}</article_summary>
<article_link>http://slim.phaziz.com/article/{{ article.id }}/</article_link>
</article>
{% endfor %}
</blog_content>
{% endblock %}
```

Will be shown as an HTML Doument, that contains the Templates as Body Text...
Header is always send as xHTML not XML

???

Thanx for helping!

Comment: Because the headers aren't being set as the content type of XML. Does this http://www.slimframework.com/read/automatically-parse-an-http-request-by-content-type help?

Comment: No, it does not :-(. I think its a problem with Twig i use as Templating Machine. When i inspect the sourcecode in Browseroutput, the XML is rendered inside the HTML-Body...

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** this answer is no longer applicable to Slim 3.

---

You have to overwrite the `Content-Type` HTTP header of the response to  `text/xml` in your `/rss/` route :

```
$app -> get('/rss/', function() use ($app) {
  $articles = Model::factory('Article') -> order_by_desc('timestamp') -> find_many();
  
  $app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
  
  return $app -> render('rss.xml', array('articles' => $articles));
});
```

http://docs.slimframework.com/response/headers/

Edit : in case if your generated XML is 100% RSS, use the `application/rss+xml` content-type instead.